# Android: onMapLoaded not called when map is hidden initially

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a `FrameLayout` containing `SupportMapFragment` in my Activity. I have set the visibility of this layout to hidden initially.

In my Map fragment, I have overridden the `onMapLoaded()` method and am loading some markers and zooming using bounds. My activity has some buttons which when pressed make the map visible and center on the location without messing the initial zoom.

Problem is, `onMapLoaded` does not get called until the map has become visible (i.e. it gets called only after the layout's visibility has been changed by a button click.). So if I start my app and click the button, map centers on the marker with default zoom.

How can I ensure `onMapLoaded` gets called even though the map is hidden?

**NOTE** I am not looking for hacking my code to make this happen. If i want hacks, I can just make the map visible and overlay it with some full screen view to hide it. I am looking for a proper solution to **How to ensure onMapLoaded gets called even though the map fragment is hidden** (if such a solution exists)

Comment: It's hard to help you without source code.

Comment: Well, pasting the complete source code would be quiet confusing since I am using custom architecture to load markers and zoom, however the simple question is "How to ensure onMapLoaded gets called even though the map fragment is hidden". This is quiet self explanatory so i refrained form posting source code.

Comment: Map can't be loaded by many reasons: no internet connection, no permission etc. Try it [all](https://www.google.com.ua/search?source=hp&q=onmaploaded+not+fired&oq=onmaploaded+not+fired&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i22i30k1.2577.15864.0.16078.27.23.4.0.0.0.315.2677.0j17j0j1.18.0.dummy_maps_web_fallback...0...1.1.64.psy-ab..5.21.2619...0j0i131k1j0i10k1j0i10i30k1j0i30k1j0i19k1j0i10i19k1j0i30i19k1j0i5i30i19k1j33i160k1.0.r62MdfVhRog).

Comment: I don't think thats the problem. note that my map is being loaded correctly, but its causing problems when the fragment is hidden initially. Even in this case, onMapReady gets called but onMapLoaded does not. It only gets called when i make the map visible atleast once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in [Official Documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback):

> `public abstract void onMapLoaded ()`
>
> Called when the map has finished rendering. This will only be called
>   once. You must request another callback if you want to be notified
>   again.
>
> This is called on the Android UI thread.

So seems it can't be called while map fragment is hidden. Moreover it newer be called even map is visible but it "is continuously changing and never completes loading due to the user constantly interacting with the map.".

Comment: Thanks. Does not solve my issue but now I know I need to think of the cleanest hack. :)

Comment: @SiddharthGarg You are welcome! Good luck in your hack :)